# Find the status of an IP

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I've been trying to find a way to check the status of IPs, specifically if an IP is in the public domain or not.

But despite my best effort, I have been unable to find a way to check for that kind of information.

So my question is pretty simple : is there a way to check for the status of a specific IP ?

Comment: what's the ip in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patents: yes.

Registered designs: yes.

Copyright: no.

Registered Trademarks: yes.

Common law Trademarks: no.

Comment: slight correction on copyright: Yes, if Author is known, then it's copyrighted till 75 Years after their death.

Comment: @Trish, copyright jurisdiction is jurisdiction dependent.

Comment: Ok but the Berne convention says at least 50 years after the author's death, while many western countries (EU, America) use the 75 years standard.

Comment: @Trish Australia is 70 as is the UK. France has different terms if the author died on active service. Mexico is 100. You can’t generalise.

Comment: @Trish, copyright is complicated.  See, for example, [this chart](https://copyright.cornell.edu/publicdomain), which covers only the situation in the US.  Depending on various factors, you may need to know when it was created, when it was first published, *where* it was first published, if it's a work of individual, anonymous, federal government, or corporate authorship, if it was published with a copyright notice, if the copyright was registered, what language it was written in, if the copyright was owned by the Alien Property Custodian, and if it's a sound recording or work of architecture.